# CiviCRM Email seems not to use Outbound Email settings

Tags: civimail

I've saved outbound email settings with:

Using sendmail
Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
Arguments: -t -i

When I press "Save and send testing email",
I can receive testing email correctly from sendmail.

But When I send email with CiviEmail, both testing and batch sendings,
Outbound email settings seems to be ignored.

It had worked correctly CiviCRM 4.6,
but suddenly broken after I upgraded CiviCRM to 5.9.1.

I noticed this issue, because I am doing relay_host settings with sendmail.
It worked on 4.6, but after I upgraded, it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Here is my sendmail setting.
It is working, but when I use CiviEmail it seems not to be used.

relayhost = [domain.for.send]:25
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_tls_security_level = verify
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_fallback_relay  = [localhost]

Comment: I found this is caused by that "From" email field has changed to like b.9271.665034.a72ea4b63703832c@[mydomain] from my specified from email.

Even if I specify -f arguments with sendmail on both /etc/php.ini and Outbound email settings, it doesn't affected. I will appreciate any suggestions and comments. my CiviCRM VERP setting is off.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. 
This is caused by Civimail script automatically append -f[Return-Path] params when it sends any email.

I fixed CiviCRM core code

packages/Mail/mail.php
and
packages/Mail/sendmail.php

to prevent that.